# Can I integrate my sentiment analyzer program with some of the capabilities of Bluemix and offer it up as a product to potential customers?

Tags: algorithm, ibm-cloud, text-analysis

I am developing a Text Analyzer for sentiment analysis. Can I integrate my program with some of the capabilities of Bluemix and offer it up as a product to potential customers? If I have my own programming and sentiment algorithms, are there any issues obtaining my own IP alongside Watson-Bluemix? As long as I pay the license fee, are there any issues offering up my own product that utilizes some of the Bluemix platform?

Comment: Might be better to ask this on "Ask DW" https://www.ibmdw.net/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a legal issue, not a programming issue. It may be more appropriate on another Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Because this question is not a technical programming question, please ask on the dW Answers site at this URL: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smartspace/bluemix/